# Why array save last data and doesn't clears?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, devextreme

I have a simple `AngularJs` application of medical cards.

I have storage with it and display it at my `home.html` using `dx-datagrid`:

[image]

One card has many records, I get records of card from `recordsArray` by `cardId`

```
 getVardsRecordsByCardId: function (id, recordsArray) {
        if (recordsArray.length != 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < recordsArray.length; i++) {
                if (recordsArray[i].cardId === id) {
                    cardsRecords = cardsRecords.concat(recordsArray[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        return cardsRecords;

    }
```

Now I have records just in the third card. I added a function on button for testing it:

```
 var jdskla = [];
var localCardId = 0;
$scope.showCardDetails = {
    text: "",
    type: "default",
    icon: "preferences",
    onClick: function () {
        if ($scope.itemIdFromShowButton) {
            $location.path('/carddetail/' + $scope.itemIdFromShowButton);
            var jdskla =[];
            var jdskla = businessLogicOfMyApp.getVardsRecordsByCardId($scope.itemIdFromShowButton, $scope.recordsArray);
            console.log($scope.itemIdFromShowButton)
            console.log(jdskla);

        }
        else {
            alert("Error!!!");
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

1,3,1 is `cardId`'s and `array` of records. But, why `array` of card records  don't clears and save last data?

May be somebody know how I can resolve it? Thanks for your answers!

P.S. I'm using `ng-view` directive in my app and i tried to clear my `array` use another button:

```
 $scope.backToGeneralPage = {
    text: "Back",
    onClick: function () {
        jdskla = [];
        $location.path('/');
    }
};
```

but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I think you want to just change where you used array.concat to array.push.

Comment: @Mike Feltman, thank you, i changed it, but it still don't works.

Comment: Note that you use `var jdskla` twice in different javascript scopes so there are actually 2 different variables with same name

Comment: @charlietfl oh, you finded mistake, thanks, but it still don't works, I haven't ideas why .

Comment: If you are doing this in different controllers  should use service to store the data

Comment: @charlietfl I use one controller :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize cardsRecords array in function getVardsRecordsByCardId.

```
 getVardsRecordsByCardId: function (id, recordsArray) {
    var cardsRecords = []; // initialize array locally
    if (recordsArray.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < recordsArray.length; i++) {
            if (recordsArray[i].cardId === id) {
                cardsRecords.push(recordsArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return cardsRecords;
}
```

Comment: oh god, i initialized it in my factory, after i initialized inside my method it works, thank you!